# How to display words that appear more than 'x' times in a text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am tiring to display, words from a text which appear more than `x` times.
`x` can be any number 
I tried to `splitting` the word by spaces and putting in to an `array`. But I am not getting the expected answer.
If anyone have a idea

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string text = "yay blah blah blah blah woo woo yay yay yay.";

var words = Regex.Split(text, @"\W+")
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(w => w)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 3)
    .Select(g => g.Key);

words.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Output:

> yay
>   blah

Answer (score 0):

Although not being for sure the best (read most efficinent) way to solve the problem, you can start by splitting the text by spaces, commas, semi-colons and the like. Then, for each word in the resulting list you try to add it to a `Dictionary<string,int>`:

```
if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(word, out int count))
{
    dictionary.Add(word, 1);
}
else
{
    dictionary[word] += 1;
}
```

Then, you loop through the dictionary and get every key having a count of three or more.

Comment: Before the question was edited there was no Linq requirement.